# Connect to SQL server (Windows Authentication) via Classic ASP

Tags: sql, authentication, asp-classic, ado

hey, I wanna connect to sql with windows Authentication either sql server authentication but frankly i can't :

this is my connection string :

```
<%
Dim conn
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
'conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source = (local); Initial Catalog = Northwind; User Id=Mohammad-PC/Mohammad; Password="
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source = (local); Initial Catalog = Northwind; User Id=sa; Password="
If conn.errors.count = 0 Then
Response.Write "Connected OK"
End If
%>
```

and i get this error :

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server: Login timeout expired
```

i've set session timeout to 10mins but still same.
i use IIS 7.5 and sql server 2005

Comment: Ok this might be a silly question, but.... is your SQL server started?

Comment: fill in the correct passwords?

Answer (score 1):

The [msdn-support](http://eedle.typepad.com/eedle/2011/01/solving-login-timeout-expired-problem.html) gives a couple of hints, mostly about the firewall configuration and the port the database engine listens to which might not be the standard 1433 due to security issues.
Try adding the port number to the Data Source, sth like:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source = (local),[port]; Initial Catalog = Northwind; User Id=sa; Password=[password]"
```

Have a look here:
  [Solving 'Login timeout expired' Problem](http://eedle.typepad.com/eedle/2011/01/solving-login-timeout-expired-problem.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
(local)
```

is probably not getting resolved.  Try localhost or even 127.0.0.1